# Error: "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" when installing lingpy1.0.1 in Python 2.7x86- Windows 7 machine

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to install lingpy-1.0.1 using Python 2.7 on a Windows 7 machine.  I have installed using manual install and easy_install, and both times I get the error: "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

The screen capture of the error can be found here: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnf9.png

How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: afaik i think you need to install MS Visual Studio 2008 to get this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's looking for a Visual Studio installation.  You can use GCC instead; you can download [this set](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries) that'll configure Python for you automatically.  Or if you prefer you can install [MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) and edit distutils.cfg under your Python's \Lib\distutils folder to look something like this:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```